# Почему вызывается метод onDetach при возвращении к предыдущему фрагменту в стеке фрагментов?

Tags: android, android-fragment

Есть 2 фрагмента A и B.
Фрагмент B можно добавить в стек фрагментов следующим методом.

```
Fragment b = new B();
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().addToBackStack(null).replace(R.id.new_fragment_container, b).commit();
```

На фрагменте B есть кнопка назад. При нажатии на которую выполняется код.

```
FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
if (fm.getBackStackEntryCount() > 0)
    fm.popBackStack();
else
    finish();
```

После выполнения этого кода, выполняется метод `onDetach()` у фрагмента B, затем из стека достается фрагмент A.
Почему у этого фрагмента A так же срабатывает метод `onDetach()` в момент доставания его из стека?

Порядок вызовов методов фрагмена А, после возращения его из стека.

```
onCreateView()

onAtach()

onDestroyView()

ondestroy()

onDetach()

onCreateView()

onStart()

onResume()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все из-за того, что ты используешь здесь *replace*. Как следует из названия, он убивает предыдущий фрагмент, заменяя его новым. Если ты не хочешь, чтобы фрагмент А уничтожался, используй *add*.